# I have to go to school. I have to go to the school

Tags: articles, zero-article

I have to go to school. 
I have to go to the school. 
Which is correct sentence? 
Can we use article before the word "School"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to go to school

is correct, although adding "the" is not grammatically wrong.

Adding "the" implies that you are talking about the location of the school, or a particular school. "Going to school" on the other hand means that you attend school in general. This does not just apply to the verb "to go".

You would say

> I would rather play computer games, but I have to go to school.

or

> I want to become a banker, but I have to go school first.

The article relating to the location would be used like this:

> I need to pick up Debbie from the cinema, but I have to go to the
> school first to pick up Nick.

Examples without the "to go":

> Where was the event held? -At the school. (The event was physically placed at the location of the school)
>
> Where did Hanna meet her husband? -At school (She met her husband when she was attending school)